# Problems with Spring on Red Hat Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, jar, oracle11g

Am new to Spring 3.x and the application utilizing Spring 3.x works well on Solaris10 with the bundled jars that I downloaded from [Spring Source Site](http://www.springsource.org/download/community?project=Spring%2520Framework&version=3.0.3.RELEASE). Wondering if the same set of jars would work on Red Hat linux as well for a standalone application? The reason I ask that is because I see `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` during database operations using Spring Jdbc template. Is `org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.3.RELEASE` platform specific? Note that the non-Spring applications work fine. Would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on this.

Comment: confirm that you: 1. have a db listener running. 2. are using the correct connection parameters. and 3. have the correct login information.

Comment: I confirm all of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for me Spring 3.2.1 works on RedHat well.

I think you have some network-related or database-related problem.

Comment: Why does non Spring application interacting with database work fine then? Is there any fundamental difference between how jdbc iteract with database versus Spring jdbc template?

Comment: Maybe database not allows to connect from your RedHat host

Comment: There are other applications running fine on Red Hat utilizing database.

Comment: Maybe post the part of the Spring application context XML which wires your Jdbc Template, and your non-spring jdbc config file. There must be a config difference somewhere. The Spring jars are definitely platform independent.

Comment: or could it be ojdbc6.jar which is not platform independant?